# Laravel: undefined variable posts within website

Tags: laravel

Really struggling here, trying to display the posts on my page, bare in mind these posts are displaying on other pages. However i cannot display them on my index.php page.

welcome.blade.php

```
@if(count($posts) > 1)
    @foreach($posts as $post)
        <h2><a href="/posts/{{$post->id}}">{{$post->title}}</a></h2>
    @endforeach
@else
    </p>no posts found</p>
@endif
```

WelcomeController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::all();
    return view('Pages.welcome')->with('posts', $posts);
}
```

PostsController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::all();
    return view('posts.index')->with('posts', $posts);
}
```

Web.php (routes)

```
  Route::get('/', 'PageController@index');
  Route::get('/welcome','PageController@Welcome');
  Route::get('/services', 'PageController@services');
  Route::get('/register', 'PageController@register');
  Route::get('/Create', 'PageController@Create');
  Route::get('/search', 'PageController@search');
  Route::get('/payment', 'PageController@Payment');



  Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');
  Route::resource('search', 'SearchController');
  Route::resource('reviews', 'ReviewsController');
```

HomeController.php

```
    public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

/**
 * Show the application dashboard.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
 */
public function index()
{
    return view('home');
}
```

I have put postscontroller because this controller works and displays data to other pages (posts.index), however when i try to display data on Pages.index i am unable to do so ?

Comment: That `index.php` is `Pages.index`? (Should be `index.blade.php` then) Have you tried to `dd($posts)` in your HomePageController? What's the route for that?

Comment: Show to us your index.blade.php route, please.

Comment: @LucasPiazzi how would i show the route, the routes i currently have are all in web.php, am i possibly missing something ?

Comment: @codingkid i need to know where you are calling the HomePageController.php. You 've made the resource controller for the post model but you are using another controller to get your posts for the index.blade.php. I expected something like this: `` Route::get('/index',' HomePageController@index'); ``

Comment: @LucasPiazzi please see the edited code

Comment: could you dd($posts) in your HomePageController.php and see what you get?

Comment: @LucasPiazzi really sorry, knew to laravel, what do you mean by dd ?

Comment: Put this in your HomePageController.php and then run again:      public function index() { $posts = Post::all(); dd($posts);}

Comment: @LucasPiazzi still receiving the same error

Comment: oh, you should be seeing a object in your page. Make sure you are on the right URL path. With this dd you should'nt be able to access this page. DD means dump and die, the code should not return a view after that command. You are accessing the /index right?

Comment: i shall try this, cant this chat be moved to the discussion chat ?

Comment: i am still recieving this error

Comment: see my answer below

Comment: First of all, in your route file, you should map`'/welcome` to `WelcomController` instead of `PageController`. Secondly, welcome blade file has a typo on `foreach`. Trying to tidy up your code style a bit can help a lot

Comment: hi fred thanks for the insight, i have now changed both and will update both the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are accessing the right path on your URL. In this case you should access `localhost:8000/welcome` .

In your route

```
Route::get('/index','PageController@HomePage');
```

Shoud be

```
Route::get('/welcome','WelcomeController@index');
```

because your controller file name is WelcomeController.php and you need to redirect to your index function in that controller.

Make sure you are redirecting to the right view in your controller

     `public function index()
    {
        $posts = Post::all();
        return view('Pages.welcome', compact('posts'));
    }`

Here you are seeking the welcome.blade.php file in your /Pages directory

Comment: hey dude i noticed you have an email, may i email you regarding this and we can talk else where on this ? i changed this and it did not work

Comment: oh, you can call me on the chat here, its easier

Comment: still receiving the same error: $posts is undefined
Make the variable optional in the blade template. Replace

Comment: $posts is undefined
Make the variable optional in the blade template. Replace {{ $posts }} with {{ $posts ?? '' }}

Comment: also, whats the name of the view you are accessing? it is index.blade.php?

Comment: yep index.blade.php

Comment: You have another route using the /index path? they may be colliding

Comment: Change the return method to this:   return view('Pages.index', compact('posts'));

Comment: i am going to change the name index to home and see what this does as i do feel they might be colliding

Comment: i have now changed my names to 'Welcome' to get away from the word index, please check see if anything is wrong

Comment: Hi i tried the edited work and it still did not work, this is really strange im not sure why this is not working

Comment: This  should work, my guess is that is some routes that are colliding or you are accessing the wrong path, try commenting the ` Route::resource('posts', 'PostsController');` and see what you get

Comment: hi lucas are you able to move this discussion to chat as i think i know what the issue might be

Comment: Yes, you can call me there

Comment: sorry for the late reply, i noticed that   Route::get('/', 'PageController@index'); is already a route for the homepage. That route is a route to get to the homepage. The function index already exists and i tried using a different function, how would i now code this, i have updated my question to show what the that route looks like.

Answer (score 0):

**Your controllers and routes are fine but you miss-spell foreach**

```
@foreac h($posts as $post)
```

**Replace with :**

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
```

now this should work

Comment: i noticed dw i sorted this earlier, i shall edit the code above, unfortunately this did not work

Comment: Ok check your route file check for spelling mistakes or syntax error looks like spelling or syntax mistake